# Cant find code tables in DOL OSHA enforcement dataset

Tags: labor

I am trying to find "code tables" in OSHA enforcement dataset of the DOL.
Code tables have been mentioned in the inspection table of DOL OSHA enforcement data set:

```
Column Name       Data Type    Column Description
const_end_use     varchar(1)   Construction - end-use **(code table ENDU)** 
project_cost      varchar(1)   Construction - project cost range **(code table COST)** 
project_type      varchar(1)   Construction - project type (code table PTYP)
```

But I have no idea how to get these codes or let alone where are they located...

Answer (score 1):

Enigma Public has ingested this dataset and they provide metadata for the columns you're looking for. It looks like the [OSHA - Accidents](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/osha-accidents/d38f9417-89e8-4b4b-88ec-a279ebdbaa35) dataset provides information on both the project cost code and the project cost description of the code. Similarly, it also provides information on the Construction - end-use code and description of the code. I hope this helps!